# Prove or disprove $bd(E)$ is nowhere dense for $E \subseteq X$ complete metric space

Tags: metric-spaces

I know this is not true but need to find an example of complete metric space $X$ with subset $E$ such that $\overline{bd(E)}$ has non-empty interior.

Comment: Perhaps you know of  some subset of $\mathbb R$ that is dense but has empty interior.

Comment: Ah, the rationals are dense in $\mathbb{R}$ but any open ball centered at $q \in \mathbb{Q}$ contains irrationals. So do we see $\mathbb{Q}$ as the boundary of the irrationals?

Comment: No, $\mathbb Q$ is not the boundary of the irrationals.  Use the definition of "boundary" to find what that boundary is.

Comment: Oh duh, $\mathbb{R}$ is the boundary, since it's the intersection of the closure of the rationals and the closure of irrationals. And $\mathbb{R}$ is its own closure, which has non-empty interior.

Answer (score 1):

The boundary of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{R}$ (usual metric) is $\mathbb{R}$. The boundary of an *open* set (or equivalently a closed set) *is* nowhere dense.